# Python: if X is detected more than T seconds:

Tags: python, if-statement, time, tracking, seconds

I am looking for Knowledge.

I'm new to python and need to do a project with a camera Gravity: HuskyLens.
It allows you to display blocks when it detects faces (around the face, it's tracking in summary)
And I would like, when I detect a Block, to know if it is detected for more than 7 seconds.

```
import time
import json
from huskylib import HuskyLensLibrary

# Initialize
#hl = HuskyLensLibrary("I2C", "", address = 0x32)
hl = HuskyLensLibrary("SERIAL", "/dev/ttyUSB0", 3000000)

# Change to face recognition algorithms
hl.algorithms("ALGORITHM_FACE_RECOGNITION")

timer = time.time()

while True:
    blocks = hl.requestAll()

    for block in blocks:
        if block.type == "BLOCK": # If a block is detected
            print("Face !")
            if BLOCK DETECTED MORE THAN 7 SECONDS: # If a block is detected more than 7 seconds
                print("SCREAMER ! BOO !")
                time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            print("No Face !")
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

I do not know if it is sufficiently clear, I am interested in any information allowing me to progress

ps: I have already gone for a walk on the Time library but I have not managed to understand everything and therefore find my happiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but you could try to track what the latest block was, and then as long as the type of the latest block is `"BLOCK"`, you can increase the timer.

What I mean:

```py
face_apparition_time = 0  # We haven't seen a face yet, so apparition time is 0
# Gives a time in seconds since a fixed point we don't control, we'll use it as a checkpoint
timer = time.time()
last_block_seen = None  # Begin with None, we haven't seen any block yet

while True:
    blocks = hl.requestAll()

    for block in blocks:
        if block.type == "BLOCK":  # If a block is detected
            print("Face !")

            # Then we check if the last block was also a "BLOCK". If yes, we increase our timer.
            if last_block_seen == "BLOCK":
                # We count the number of seconds between the last checkpoint and now.
                face_apparition_time = time.time() - timer

            # Then we chack if a face has appeared for more than 7 seconds:
            if face_apparition_time > 7:  # If a block is detected more than 7 seconds.
                print("SCREAMER ! BOO !")

        else:
            print("No Face !")

            # As we don't see no face, we have to reset our checkpoint to "now"
            timer = time.time()
            face_apparition_time = 0

        # Do not forget that we are going to look at the next block, so this block must be stored :)
        last_block_seen = block.type
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

I'm not sure of where the `time.sleep()` should go, you can try yourself what suits better :)
Hope this helps, do not hesitate for further questions!

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your answer, it works almost as it should, the concern is that time is running and if I am for example at 5 seconds and I detect a face, it only takes 2 seconds to display the "SCREAMER BOO" and not 7 .

There is also a point that I do not quite understand, the part:
face_apparition_time = time.time () - timer 
Since "timer = time.time()" (above), why doesn't that add up to 0? It's certainly a silly question but I'd rather ask than block on it

Since it's surely in this part that I don't understand that the solution must be found, I have trouble unblocking it.

Comment: Actually (you can try yourself), `time.time()` returns the actual number of seconds counted from a fixed moment (like, from january 1, 1900 by example) to now. So it will change every second.

So you would get, at a time `t`, let's say 125.003 seconds. And if you call it again at `t + 3` seconds, you would get 125.006 seconds. Then you have to make the dfference between both to know that there has been 3 seconds between `t` and `t + 3`.